# strange act of date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I just working on date comparison but face something strange with date. my code is something like below code

```
var now = new Date(); 
var from = new Date(2013,12,18,7,41,25,0);
var untill = new Date(2013,12,18,8,42,25,0);

if(now <= untill && now >= from){
...
}else{
....
}
```

this condition in a right time for example 2013/12/18 7:42:00 doesn't work.
I get further investigate about it with console.log :

```
console.log(from);
console.log(now);
console.log(untill);
```

the output was as strange as below:

```
Date {Sat Jan 18 2014 07:41:25 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)}
Date {Wed Dec 18 2013 08:20:22 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)}
Date {Sat Jan 18 2014 08:42:25 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)}
```

As you can see it's a date for from and untill variable is 2014 January 18 in spite of entered 2013 / 12 / 18

Please help me to figure out why javascript act such this.

Comment: [Please read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date): *"month: Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The month argument uses 0-based indexing.

Use `var from = new Date(2013,11,18,7,41,25,0);` for December.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript months are 0-indexed, so January is 0, December is 11.

Change your code to

```
var from = new Date(2013,11,18,7,41,25,0);
var untill = new Date(2013,11,18,8,42,25,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because the `Month` and the `Day of the week` These are based on `0-based indexing`.

you can read about the `Date` in more detail here. [Date in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: The day of the month (which is what is used here) is not 0 based. Its values are 1 through 31, as expected. The day of the week is 0 based though.

Comment: @FelixKling OOps my mistake it was a typing mistake, I was thinking about the day of the week and written the day will edit my answer thanks.